# Makeshift Junction Box Cover

Tags: junction-box

I'm about to cover up some junction boxes in my ceiling, they need a cover and I got the wrong size at the store.

I have some metal flashing laying around from working on my roof would this be safe to use if I cut it to size and screw it on?

Comment: Why can't you just go back to the store?

Comment: I can, it's just a 45 minute drive from me.

Comment: Yeah -- this would be a good time to take advantage of whatever return policy the store provides, too

Comment: Electrical boxes, enclosures, covers, etc. must be "listed" for the purpose, yes?

Comment: Only use metal to cover your junction box if the box is metal too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't knock yourself out making a special trip, but do go get correct, listed box covers eventually when you get a chance.  Homebrew covers are not legal.     Most of the covers I use are on the order of a dollar, so I don't worry too much about keeping a few in stock.